# What is black box testing and white box testing

Tags: testing, black-box, white-box

I'm trying to understand one in terms of how it compares to the other.

Is white box testing where you can see the code and black box testing where you don't look at the code?

Comment: See the previously existing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402161/black-box-vs-white-box-testing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

basicaly yes.

in black box testing you test if the expected input to your object produces expected output without the ability to change the underlying code.

in white box testing you can see the code and you test all possible paths through it.

Comment: They should call it clear box testing instead of white box testing.

Comment: Also be aware that if you have a code branch that you aren't able to exercise using a valid blackbox test case, then you are either trying to test for something incidental and irrelevant or you have found some dead code.

Comment: I have a question: "you can test all possible paths through it". So which one I should do? Test all the possible paths through the UI of the program or just writing test scenarios in the code to do test?

Answer (score 10):

Q) Is white box testing where you can see the code and black box testing where you don't look at the code?

### Black-Box Testing

- It is a process of giving the input to the system and checking the output of the system, without bothering about the system that how the system generates the output. It is also call as behavior testing, data-driven testing or I/O driven testing, functional testing .
- testing based solely on analysis of requirements (specification, user documentation etc)

**Advantages:**

1) More effective on larger units of code than glass-box testing.

2) Tester and Programmer are independent of each other.

3) Tests done according to users point of view.

4) test-cases can be designed as soon as specifications are complete.

**Disadvantages:**

1) It may leave many program path untested.

2) Only small number of possible inputs can actually be tested, to test every possible.
   input stream would take nearly forever.

### White-Box Testing

- It is a process of giving input to thee system and checking that how the system processes the input to generate the output.
- It is mandatory for tester to have the knowledge of the code.

**Advantage:**

1) This type of testing helps to uncover defects at structural level. The tests go below the top and functional layer to uncover the defects

**Disadvantages:**

1) Does not ensure the user requirements are met

2) Does not establish if the decisions, condition ans paths.

Comment: Very good answer. But it seems like the last sentence is cut off?

Comment: Disadvantage for whitebox testing is also that it is highly coupled to the implementation, and needs to change whenever there is an incidental change to the implementation that doesn't change the behavior. So whitebox testing has higher maintenance.

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia:

> [White box testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing) uses an
>   internal perspective of the system to
>   design test cases based on internal
>   structure. It requires programming
>   skills to identify all paths through
>   the software.

versus

> [Black box testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box_testing) takes an
>   external perspective of the test
>   object to derive test cases.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you pretty much have it.  Black box is testing the externals without knowledge (or access) of/to anything internal.  White box testing is being able to look at (and perhaps modify) the internal state of what you are testing.  They both have different uses.  Unit tests are most often (but not always) white box tests.

Comment: Unit tests test particular functions typically at a very granular level.  They are the lowest level tests and they are typically created by the developers of the application and formed in to a regression test suite comprised of hundreds or thousands of them which can be run anytime things change to detect a regression.

Answer (score 1):

**White box testing**

Once the internal working of s/w is known, the test is performed to ensure that all the internal operations of s/w are performed according to specification.

**Black box testing**

Once the specified function for each s/w compnent have been designed, the test is performed to ensure that each function is performing.

Answer (score 1):

white-box testing:  In white box testing we use knowledge of the internal structure of system i.e. tester needs to have knowledge of programming language and coding.

and in black box testing we ignore the internal of the system and focus on the relationship between inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 1):

**White box testing** is like a giving input and verifying output using (glass) transparent box
i.e. in this you give the input **observe the processing on input** (functional flow, variables values, calculation) and verifies the output is as expected or not.

**Black box testing** is like giving input and verifying output using (wooden) non-transparent box
i.e. in this you give the input **don't observe the processing on input** (functional flow, variables values, calculation) and verifies the output is as expected or not.

Answer (score 0):

**White box testing :-**
Programming and implementation knowledge is required.

**Black box testing :-**
Programming and implementation knowledge is not required.

Comment: You can write blackbox unit tests. For those you most definitely need to be able to write code.